# How do i specify the path in node/express correctly to read my certificate files?

Tags: node.js, express

This is my file structure simplified

```
app-folder
   -> dist
      -> server.js
   -> src
      -> server.ts
   -> key.pem
   -> cert.pem
```

This is the simplified content of the server.ts file to read the certificate files

```
import fs from 'fs';

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('../key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('../cert.pem')
};
```

This is the error i am getting

```
server     | internal/fs/utils.js:307
server     |     throw err;
server     |     ^
server     | 
server     | Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../key.pem'
server     |     at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
server     |     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
server     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/dist/server.js:18:23)
server     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
server     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
server     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
server     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
server     |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
server     |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
server     |   errno: -2,
server     |   syscall: 'open',
server     |   code: 'ENOENT',
server     |   path: '../key.pem'
server     | }
server exited with code 1
```

I created the key and certificate following this
[tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/)

Hoangdv pointed out that i use docker which is correct this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14


# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN npm install -g nodemon


# Install dependencies
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

RUN npx tsc

EXPOSE 8080
```

Does `COPY . .` not copy the certificates already?

Comment: It seems you are using docker, let's copy certificates file to `/usr/src/app`.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths will be resolved relative to the current working directory as determined by calling `process.cwd()`.

--- [node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v15.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_file_paths)

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../cert.pem'))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
var resolve = require('path').resolve
key : resolve('../key.pem')
cert : resolve('../cert.pem')
```